# Ways to transition SELinux domain / process context (securing SELinux boundaries)

Tags: selinux

(Apologies for multi-question. Theme is the same, but there are quite a few edge cases.)

Browsing the web, I come across resources (see below), but they don't make this quite clear what the situation really is, so this is my attempt to clarify and gather info that I am missing.

---

### Ways to transition

I gather there are at least three ways for process to transition into another domain. I will list them as rules that are displayed by *sesearch*:

1. "**type_transition** <source> <file_label>:process <target>" - process in *source* domain can execute a file with *file_label*, which will automatically transition to *target* domain.
2. "allow <source> self:process **setexec**" - process in *source* domain can use `setexeccon` (`/proc/self/attr/exec`) to transition into *target* domain when `exec` is called.
3. "allow <source> self:process **setcurrent**" - process in *source* domain can use `setcon` (`/proc/self/attr/current`) to transition into *target* domain immediately.

Are there any other ways?

---

### Protections for these transitions

Besides the above rules, transitions will also require following permissions:

- "allow <source> <file_label>:file { **execute read getattr** }" - for *type_transition*, *setexec* (and *setcurrent*?)
- "allow <target> <file_label>:file **entrypoint**" - for *type_transition*, *setexec* (and *setcurrent*?)
- "allow <source> <target>:process **transition**" - for *type_transition* and *setexec*
- "allow <source> <target>:process **dyntransition**" - for *setcurrent*

---

### Other potential problems

- In case of **memfd**_create+exec("/proc/self/fd/%d"), is the *file_label* same as the "symlink" label? I assume for normal /proc/self/fd/ entries symlink would be followed, so that should be fine.
- Can a **ptrace**d process transition to another domain? Experiments tell me exec fails with EPERM in case of *type_transition*, and there's a denial logged because of missing process *ptrace* permission from *source* to *target*. Would this work with *dyntransition*?
- *type_transition* requires a file with correct label. That can be created if one has proper *relabelfrom* and *relabelto* permissions.

---

Resources:

- https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_Domain_and_Object_Transitions
- https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_ObjectClassesPermissions
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/How_does_a_process_get_into_a_certain_context
- [The SELinux Notebook 4th Edition](https://www.lesstif.com/system-admin/files/23756930/24313869/1/1417836658000/The_SELinux_Notebook-4th_Edition.pdf)